# Date Picker not updating - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC 3 Razor with Entity Framework

In my edit form I need to edit a StartDate field with the following code:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
```

When editing the date picker opens up fine, I select a different date but then the date in the textbox doesn't update.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of date-picker are you using jquery date-picker and can you be more specific is it update or insert action.

Comment: It's the date picker that comes with @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate) - I've also tried the telerik datepicker and the same thing happens. I'm probably missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just reply, but I don't have that priveledge yet. I recommend using firebug or some other tool to watch for javascript errors. If it is not populating the text box, then something is breaking down on the client side. Could be you're missing a script or an error somewhere else on the page is causing it to break down.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was loading Jquery twice. Normal loading of Jquery and then Telerik Scriptmanager